# Text rotation in GeoGraphics

Tags: text, geographics, rotation

I have a problem rotating some text in GeoGraphics. Whenever I rotate the text I am also getting a shift in the latitude.

- OS: Linux x86 (64-bit)
- FullVersionNumber: 12.1.1

As a minimum working example (taken from the documentation and simply adding a text) is the following:

```
GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "UnitedKingdom"], GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"London","GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]], Style[Text["Something",GeoPosition[{59.88295193293852, -4.916961348517941}]], {15}]}]
```

which works as expected.

However, if I use [Rotate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html) the resulting rotated text is shifted in the latitude :

```
GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "UnitedKingdom"], GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"London","GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]], Rotate[Style[Text["Something",GeoPosition[{59.88295193293852, -4.916961348517941}]], {15}],Pi/2]}]
```

The following code produces somehow the desired outcome, but I have to shift the latitude exactly by 15 Degrees:

```
GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "UnitedKingdom"], GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"London","GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]], Rotate[Style[Text["Something",GeoPosition[{74.88295193293852, -4.916961348517941}]], {15}],Pi/2]}]
```

Any ideas, what is happening? Is this the expected behaviour?

Thanks,
Dimitris

Comment: Thanks for your answers! There is still an open point from me. Is this the expected behaviour?
@Zviovich, "order of functions do matter", that 's true but not for the case of Rotate and Graphics. Please have a look on the following:

Graphics[Rotate[Text[Style["something",18],{12,12}],Pi/4],  Axes -> True]

Graphics[Text[Rotate[Style["something", 18], Pi/4], {12, 12}], Axes -> True]

Graphics[Text[Style[Rotate["something", Pi/4], 18], {12, 12}],  Axes -> True]

These inputs give the same result. Why is this not the case also for GeoGraphics? Why does the order matter for GeoGraphics?

Answer (score 6):

Rotate and style the string *before* using `Text` to set the position on the map.

```
GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "UnitedKingdom"],
  GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"London","GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]],
  Text[Rotate[Style["Something", 15], Pi/2],
    GeoPosition[{59.88295193293852, -4.916961348517941}]]}]
```

[image: rotated text]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the fourth argument of `Text` to rotate the label instead of using `Rotate`:

```
GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "UnitedKingdom"], 
  GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]], 
  Style[Text["Something", GeoPosition[{59.88295193293852, -4.916961348517941}], 
    {Center, Center}, {0, 1}], 
  15, Bold, Red]}]
```

[image]

Replace `{0,1}` with `Through[{Cos, Sin}[Pi/4]]` to get

[image]

```
ListAnimate[Table[
  GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "UnitedKingdom"], 
    GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]], 
    Style[Text["Something", 
     GeoPosition[{59.88295193293852, -4.916961348517941}], 
     {Center, Center}, t], 15, Bold, Red]}],
  {t, CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 36]}], 
  DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Order of functions do matter. Set up the text first with Style, then rotate and finally place in the map. Added a point in the map to ensure that the text is placed where you wanted.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{txtPoint = 
    GeoPosition[{59.88295193293852, -4.916961348517941}]}, 
  GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[
     Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]], 
    Point[GeoPosition@txtPoint], 
    Text[Rotate[Style["Something", 12], angle], 
     GeoPosition[txtPoint]]}, GeoRange -> "Country"]], {angle, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]